# Android No view found for id with exoplayer controller

Tags: android, fragment, exoplayer

I'm trying to put a fragment in a FrameView of my custom ExoPlayer controller but I'm getting this error:

"No view found for id 0x7f0a00e8 (com.example.myapp:id/frame_detail) for fragment detailFragment"

Custom controller:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/playerControllerView">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code:

```
public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
    if(visibility == 0){
        detailFragment dfrg = new detailFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_detail, dfrg, "detailFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This code is on the visibility change of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get the exception because the fragment transaction internally uses a similar mechanism to `findViewById(int id)` which will also return null. You need to call this code from the activity you're working with.

If you are using the view from the activity (or fragment, same thing in this case), try doing this.

Change this line:

`FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

to this:

`FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

which then should find the view ID you are looking for since it will search from the activity itself.

Comment: Hi, this is done inside of a fragment, casting with AppCompatActivity still gives me the same error. What should I do? Thanks